# Ubuntu software center Hanging

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 for last 4 months. It was working properly but suddenly the Ubuntu software center has started hanging.Now it doesn't open. And every time I try to open it, I have to force quit it. So that I am not able to install the software that I need.I am in a great problem... What do I do? please help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Ubuntu Software Center ever be usable? (keeps hanging and freezing)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171726/will-ubuntu-software-center-ever-be-usable-keeps-hanging-and-freezing)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the Lubuntu Software Center. It's much faster and I've never experienced a problem with it. If it hangs also then you may have to reinstall your system.